# Smart Phone Like Scrolling Solution issue (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, scroll, touchscreen

This solution seems to be the best one out there and the most commonly accepted one - however, if you scroll to the bottom and touch a the actual flowcontrol behind the buttons (I tried to make this so that there would be empty space to make this sample test easier), you then have to double tap-and-hold the button for the scrolling to resume. Restarting the application restores the phone-like scrolling functionality. I am wondering if anyone else has seen this or figured it out - try it with your apps and see if it is the case as well. I modified the snippet above so that you can start a new project, copy and paste this into form1's code, and hit run.

```
 Public Class Form1
        Dim FlowPanel As New FlowLayoutPanel
        Private Function GenerateButton(ByVal pName As String) As Button
            Dim mResult As New Button
            With mResult
                .Name = pName
                .Text = pName
                .Width = 128
                .Height = 128
                .Margin = New Padding(0)
                .Padding = New Padding(0)
                .BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
                AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf Button_MouseDown
                AddHandler .MouseMove, AddressOf Button_MouseMove
            End With

            Return mResult
        End Function



        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            Me.Width = 806
            Me.Height = 480
            FlowPanel.Padding = New Padding(0)
            FlowPanel.Margin = New Padding(0)
            ' FlowPanel.ColumnCount = Me.Width / (128 + 6)
            FlowPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            FlowPanel.AutoScroll = True
            Me.Controls.Add(FlowPanel)
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To 98
                FlowPanel.Controls.Add(GenerateButton("btn" & i.ToString))
            Next
        End Sub

        Dim myMouseDownPoint As Point
        Dim myCurrAutoSMouseDown As Point
        Private Sub Button_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            myMouseDownPoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            myCurrAutoSMouseDown = FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                Dim mLocation As Point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
                If myMouseDownPoint <> mLocation Then
                    Dim mCurrAutoS As Point
                    Dim mDeslocation As Point = myMouseDownPoint - mLocation
                    mCurrAutoS.X = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.X) + mDeslocation.X
                    mCurrAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.Y) + mDeslocation.Y

                    FlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition = mCurrAutoS

                End If
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for the code , I made ​​some changes to improve behavior . I hope it can be useful to someone .**

```
Dim myMouseDownPoint As Point
Dim myCurrAutoSMouseDown As Point
```

**'Add boolean variable a true.**

```
Private _ValidateClickEvent As Boolean = True

Private Sub MyMouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    myMouseDownPoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    myCurrAutoSMouseDown = Panel1.AutoScrollPosition
End Sub
```

**' Add MouseUp event for return the boolean variable a true.**

```
Private Sub MyMouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    _ValidateClickEvent = True
End Sub
```

**'Set boolean variable a false when change mlocation.**

```
Private Sub MyMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim mLocation As Point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        If myMouseDownPoint <> mLocation Then
            Dim mCurrAutoS As Point
            Dim mDeslocation As Point = CType(myMouseDownPoint - mLocation, Size)
            mCurrAutoS.X = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.X) + mDeslocation.X
            mCurrAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(myCurrAutoSMouseDown.Y) + mDeslocation.Y
            Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = mCurrAutoS

            _ValidateClickEvent = False

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**' Test boolean variable to perform click event.**

```
Private Sub MyClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    If _ValidateClickEvent Then

       ........................

    Else
        _ValidateClickEvent = True
    End If
End Sub
```